# Odoo Email template not rendering

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to create a email template and trying to add some conditions

```
%if object.origin:
origin : ${object.origin or ''}
%endif
```

but when I am trying to render the template it is only rendering the $part not the %if %endif part,

so the %if and %end if looks visible in the email template, and it is not performing the conditions.

how to overcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo uses `jinja` & `mako` template engine for the email template, your code looks like you have used `mako` template, but you can try out [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) templates. After you apply the jinja template the code become different like,

```
{% if object.origin %}
origin : ${object.origin or ''}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

sharing knowledge:

> This parsing problem is likely caused by a combination of factors:
>
> The `%` syntax in Jinja2/Mako templates corresponds to line
> statements, and this only works as soon as the % sign is the first
> non-blank character on the line. When you're dealing with HTML
> templates (as is the case for email templates), there's a very very
> good chance every line has a lot of invisible HTML tags before the %
> sign, or that the % sign is not on its own line.
>
> This is invalid:
> % if object.street2: ${(object.street or '-') |
> safe}
> % endif
>
> While this is valid (even if quite strange, mixing 2 different
> fields):
> % if object.street2:
>
>  ${(object.street or '-') | safe}
> % endif

[credits to Oliver Dony (more details)](https://www.odoo.com/forum/ayuda-1/if-endif-does-not-seem-to-work-with-mail-templates-sent-e-mails-are-blank-74389#comment_forum_post_74444)